# How to go back to previous directory in .gitignore

Tags: git, phpstorm, gitignore

I use PhpStorm as my IDE and it sets up `.gitignore` file in a directory called `.idea`. There are folders and files that I want to ignore but I can't go to previous folder no matter what.

Lets have file called `example.txt`. The folder tree looks like this:

```
- /Project
  - /.idea
    - .gitignore
    - workspace.xml
  - /src
    - example.txt
```

How do I ignore `example.txt` file? I tried `../src/example.txt`, `src/example.txt`, `/../src/example.txt`

Comment: Create a new `.gitignore` file in the `Project` folder and ignore `example.txt` in that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.gitignore` applies to a directory and its subdirectories.
it does not apply to a sibling or parent directory.

to ignore the `src/example.txt` you could:

1. create a `.gitignore` file in the `src/` directory, containing e.g.

   ```
   example.txt
   ```
2. create a `.gitignore` file in the parent directory, containing e.g.

   ```
   src/example.txt
   ```

Comment: Alright, i thought you couldn't have more than 1 .gitignore file. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

If you've added `src/example.txt` to the repository, git wont ignore it even when you add `src/example.txt` to `.gitignore`. You'll need to remove it from repository like this:

```
git rm --cached src/example.txt
```

This command removes the file only from git repository. The original file will remain at `src/example.txt`

In addition, to ignore `src/example.txt`, you'll need to create a `.gitignore` file on the top level directory (on Project), and put `src/example.txt` inside it.

Answer (score 1):

If you've already pushed your files to git, though you add `example.txt` to `.gitignore`, still cached logs exist.

So, those cached logs should be removed too. Run following code.

```
$ git rm --cached `src/example.txt`
```

And also, to ignore all the files under `src` folder, then add `src/` to `.gitignore`. Then it'll ignore all the files under the folder `src/` with `src` folder itself.

If you'd like to remove all the files that are tracked, run following code.

```
$ git rm -r --cached .
```

With above command, you can clear all the cache tracking.